# how to concatenate all rows of a column into a single field Using C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I would like to know how to do this with C #:
I have a CSV file with multiple columns as follows:

[image]

I would like to concatenate the result of all the lines of the first column to have:
Name = NDECINT, NDEC, NFAC, ORIGIN .....

Comment: Why did you tag C?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for SSIS.

1. Add a variable called concat set equal to ""
2. Read the file using SSIS.
3. Add a script component
4. Pass in Row A and add variable
5. Set variable to concat += RowA + ","

When you are done, you will have an extra "," on the variable that needs to be removed.

Use an expression.

concat = left(concat, len(concat)-1)

Answer (score 0):

You said all c#. This is done with Core 5.

```
var yourData = File.ReadAllLines("yourFile.csv")
               .Skip(1)
               .Select(x => x.Split(','))
               .Select(x => new
                            {
                                Name = x[0] //only working with Name column
                                ,Type = int.Parse(x[1]) //Only added for reference for handling more columns
                            });

string namesJoined = string.Join(',', yourData.Select(x => x.Name));
```

This is **really** basic code and does not handle the crazy things that can be inside a csv like a comma in the name for example.